# Drop entire df where last row is nan

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove data from **all** rows and columns if the last row in a specified column is NaN. At present, I'm only deleting the last row from all columns.

With below, if the last row in `Volume` is NaN, then I want to delete all rows from every column. If NaN appears anywhere else in the `Volume`, then leave as is.

`df1` displays the last row as NaN, while `df2` contains NaN elsewhere in the column. I only want to remove all rows based on the last row only.

Additionally, if there are no NaN's, then leave as is.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime' : ['2022-10-10 01:44:00','2022-10-10 01:45:00','2022-10-10 01:46:00','2022-10-10 01:47:00','2022-10-10 01:48:00'],
                   'Val' : [0.97,0.97,0.95,0.93,0.96],
                   'Volume' : [0,0,np.NaN,0,np.NaN],
                  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime' : ['2022-10-10 01:44:00','2022-10-10 01:45:00','2022-10-10 01:46:00','2022-10-10 01:47:00','2022-10-10 01:48:00'],
                   'Val' : [0.97,0.97,0.95,0.93,0.96],
                   'Volume' : [0,0,np.NaN,0,0.0,
                  })

df1 = df1.loc[:df1['Volume'].last_valid_index()]

df2 = df2.loc[:df2['Volume'].last_valid_index()]
```

df1 out:

```
              Datetime   Val  Volume
0  2022-10-10 01:44:00  0.97     0.0
1  2022-10-10 01:45:00  0.97     0.0
2  2022-10-10 01:46:00  0.95     NaN
3  2022-10-10 01:47:00  0.93     0.0
```

df1 intended output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

df2 out:

```
              Datetime   Val  Volume
0  2022-10-10 01:44:00  0.97     0.0
1  2022-10-10 01:45:00  0.97     0.0
2  2022-10-10 01:46:00  0.95     NaN
3  2022-10-10 01:47:00  0.93     0.0
4  2022-10-10 01:48:00  0.96     0.0
```

df2 intended out:

```
              Datetime   Val  Volume
0  2022-10-10 01:44:00  0.97     0.0
1  2022-10-10 01:45:00  0.97     0.0
2  2022-10-10 01:46:00  0.95     NaN
3  2022-10-10 01:47:00  0.93     0.0
4  2022-10-10 01:48:00  0.96     0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select last value of column `Volume` by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) and test missing value by scalar by [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html), if True create empty DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame() if pd.isna(df['Volume'].iat[-1]) else df
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks. But that won't work for df2. It's only if last row is nan. Not any row

Comment: @Chopin - it is same like `df`, also I test only column `df['Volume']`

Comment: maybe `df.iloc[-1:].loc[:,'Specific Column'].isnull()`

Comment: @Chopin - So `df== df2` ? So same output what is expected?

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for this, works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the logic in functions if you want to generalise the functionality and keep the main code simple.

```
def make_final_column_entry_isna_check(column_name):
    def final_column_entry_isna_check(dataframe):
        return dataframe.tail(1)[column_name].isna().bool()
    return final_column_entry_isna_check

# Create a function which will check the 'Volume' column
volume_data_check = make_final_column_entry_isna_check('Volume')

def validated_dataframe(dataframe):
    return pd.DataFrame() if volume_data_check(dataframe) else dataframe

# Main code
df = validated_dataframe(df)

df2 = validated_dataframe(df2)
```